# NGINX proxy_pass rewrite asset uri

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to do a basic NGINX reverse proxy by subdomian, to localhost/folder and am stumped getting it to rewrite my assets+links.

My http://localhost:8080/myapp/ works like a charm, but via NGINX+subdomain it fails on the subfolder assets.

I believe I'm stumped on the 'rewrite' clause for NGINX.

How can I rewrite the HTML going to the client browser to drop the /myapp/ context?

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  app1.domain.com;
    location / {
        rewrite ^/myapp/(.*) /$1 break; # this line seems to do nothing
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/myapp/;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting my resultant HTML (via https://app1.domain.com) to be rewritten without the subfolder /myapp/, so when assets are requested they can be found instead of a 404 against https://app1.domain.com/myapp/assets/. It should just be https://app1.domain.com/assets/ (which if I manually go there they work)

--thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feeding from Ivan's response and finalizing my solution as:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  app1.domain.com;
    location / {
        sub_filter '/myapp/'  '/'; # rewrites HTML strings to remove context
        sub_filter_once off; # ensures it loops through the whole HTML (required)
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/myapp/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As nginx `proxy_pass` documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be determined:
>
> ...
>
> When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the rewrite directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a request (break):
>
> ```
> location /name/ {
>     rewrite    /name/([^/]+) /users?name=$1 break;
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, the URI specified in the directive is ignored and the full changed request URI is passed to the server.

So with this configuration block after you rewrite `/myapp/assets/some_asset` URI to `/assets/some_asset` and use a `break` flag, nginx ignores `/myapp/` suffix on a `proxy_pass` directive and passes `/assets/some_asset` request to your backend. However strange it is, what you need is to use this rewrite rule instead:

```
rewrite ^(/myapp/.*)$ $1 break;
```

Another (may be even better) solution is to use two `location` blocks:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/myapp/;
}
location /myapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Comment: This blurb fixed my assets [[[[rewrite ^(/myapp/.*)$ $1 break;]]]], but isn't rewriting the client-side to hide the subfolder/context. THANKS. it fixed the 'most' annoying bit. Now I just need to figure out how to get it to hide all the /myapp/ links and just consider it the root of the subdomain. Ideally tnis would fix the previous assets issue too. if /login was in fact /login instead of /myapp/login (for example).

Comment: This is a far more complex task. If you cannot make your app generate only relative links (which is probably impossible), the only way to do this is to change on-the-fly your backend response rewriting all generated links with a new ones. There is a [`ngx_http_sub_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) which can do this, but it isn't built by default, so in order to use it you have to build nginx manually from sources.

Comment: Check your nginx built parameters with the `nginx -V` command. If there is a string `--with-http_sub_module` present, you can use this module without recompiling nginx.

Comment: I may go back to my old setup. My backend is Tomcat and I used to have virtual servers for all my subdomains. That worked fine and each "app" ran as it's own root. I really dislike relative links sure to difficulty in sharing headed/footer code. But I got frustrated with Tomcats handling last week as it started deploying all my apps within all my other appbases. Super annoying. But allowing Tomcat to see the full domain request worked fine. I was hoping to simplify it with NGINX, and generic sub-apps in Tomcat.

Comment: BTW if you continue to use nginx, consider serving static files directly with nginx without passing additional requests to your backend, it would be much more efficient.

Comment: Oh I will/do. I've been running various webservices behind NGINX for years. I'm just trying to clean up + improve some stuff while developing some new things. Thanks

Comment: If you have dns example.cloud.com and need to proxy_pass by other UI example.cloud.com/service1 , how view config for proxy nginx and local nginx?